# How do I move an array element in a hash?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to put an array into hash:

```
@friends = {}
@friend = ['network' => 'facebook', 'picture' => picture, 'name' => name, 'id' => id]
```

How can I move `@friend` into `@friends` to get a result such as:

```
friends: {
  [
    'network': 'facebook',
    'picture': 'http://fb.com/myimage.jpg',
    'name':    'MyName',
    'id':      '46846546'
  ]
}
```

An `array` in `array` I can do. An `hash` in `array` I also can do. But an `array` in a `hash` - I can't find how to do it.

It might be impossible. I was searching the documentation for hashes and arrays and there was nothing about this.

for @dave newton related to last comment:

[image]

for @Borodin related to his answer:

[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. You are confused between symbol and string hash keys. Your resultant hash can have symbolic keys like `network: 'facebook'` or `:network => 'facebook'`, or it can have string keys, like `'network' => 'facebook'`. It would help if you wrote the data structure that you wanted in `irb` and showed it to us.

Comment: Your output looks like JSON. Is that what it's supposed to be?

Comment: @Borodin yes it should be a json, I'll update the question with the json I need to have

Comment: Your expected JSON isn't JSON. What are you trying to do? Every element in a hash needs a key.

Comment: You are on thin ice with your comment on the response from @justalisteningman. Your subject is *"move array element in a hash using ruby"*

Comment: -1: (very) *Unclear what you're asking*

Comment: @Borodin what exactly is not clear? imgine a hash `{}`  and an array `[]`, what I need is the array to be in hash `{[]}` what exactly it's not clear? not `array` into `array`, not `hash` into `array`.. I need `array` to be added to `hash`.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be "very" unclear.. all I need is to find out how to update a hash with an array that I have and forget about the JSON part.

Comment: *"move array element to a hash using ruby"* is your subject line, but *"I have this Ruby array that I want to look something like this invalid JSON"* is certainly not a clear question.

Comment: I strongly suspect you misunderstood what the front-end devs need; there's no such thing as an "array in a hash without a key". If you want an array in a hash, like `friends: [ ... ]` that's trivial; a JSON object with a list of friends in an array seems a reasonable, and likely, requirement.

Comment: @DaveNewton update my question, it's a screenshot of a piece of task on sprint.ly that was written by frontend devs and assigned to me. Do you think I misunderstood what they need? I know what json looks like, but I was trying to do what they requested.

Comment: @rmagnum2002: That specification is nonsense. It has arrays with keys and a hash with no keys. The `{}` and `[]` pairs should be swapped, and there should be commas between the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "put an array into a hash" to obtain something like `{[]}`. Hashes are built from key-value pairs. An array can either take the key or value role within a hash.

For example, here an array is the value and a symbol `:friends` is the key:

```
{:friends => ['Pete', 'Robert', 'Katrin']}
```

The `@friend` variable (as you have defined it) results in an array having one element, which is a hash.

```
@friend = ['network' => 'facebook', 'picture' => picture, 'name' => 'name', 'id' => 42]
#=> [{"network"=>"facebook", "picture"=>"picture", "name"=>"name", "id"=>42}]
```

I guess you want `@friend` to be a hash, and `@friends` to be an array which contains many `friend`-hashes.

Comment: "You cannot "put an array into a hash" - this is what I was looking for, as I was searching for a solution for this for a few hours and I just was thinking that this is not possible and I just needed someone else to confirm it.

Comment: and I also thought that an array of hashes would be the way to go, but as the request by front end devs was to have a hash of arrays I was looking for a way to do it, thanks to you the idea that this is not possible was confirmed and we will have to work with an array of hashes.

Comment: @rmagnum2002: I would be surprised if what you want is impossible. All you need to do is describe it. Maybe try again tomorrow?

Comment: @Borodin I have updated the question with a piece of the task that was assigned to me, in the task front end devs required the array of connections to be inside a hash, look at it and tell me I'm wrong.

Comment: @rmagnum2002: That specification is nonsense. It has arrays with keys and a hash with no keys. The `{}` and `[]` pairs should be swapped, and there should be commas between the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

That specification is nonsense. It has arrays with keys and a hash with no keys. The `{}` and `[]` pairs should be swapped, and there should be commas between the key/value pairs.

I think it is intended to look like this

```
{
  "connections" : [
    {
      "network" : "facebook",
      "picture" : "http://facebook.com/picture.jpg",
      "name" : "User Name",
      "id" : "12345679"
    },
    {
      "network" : "linkedin",
      "picture" : "http://linkedin.com/picture.jpg",
      "name" : "Another User",
      "id" : "959d919sd92"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I cannot be sure, and you need to go back and ask the question.

Comment: +1 and yes, they confirmed that it was a typo, so the response should be an array of hashes like you have here. Due to difference of 8 hours between us this confirmation came much later, so I decided to ask on SO and see if this kind of response is possible at all.. I was searching for hours and couldn't find a solution, this question on SO is just a confirmation that it's not possible to have a response as was requested in this task. Thank you.

Comment: updated the question with a chat that I had with them about this task and my question here might get more downvotes, but also it might helpfull to others as well to understand that there might be typos in the task they are working on and waste a lot of time with it.